# How generic servlet is protocol independent?

Tags: servlets

The HttpServlet is indented to handled http request only. But the generic servlet is said to be protocol independent. Then how or what make Generic servlet protocol independent. For example, if we are sending a mail from http servlet then our servlet would work on http protocol, but the mail transfering follow the the SMTP or other mail transfering protocol. Then how this http protocol request get converted to SMTP protocol ? And why generic servlet is protocol independent and how can we handled non-http protocol request ?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the Servlet class doesn't know about any protocols.  It is the HttpServlet that understands the HTTP protocol. A SMTPServlet would override the service() method of Servlet to handle, for example, the MAIL, RCPT, and DATA SMTP "verbs" - maybe with a doMail(), doRecipient(), and doData().  There would likely be other methods to handle the protocol. But the interaction would be protocol specific - thus the generic base class and protocol specific child class.

Having said that, I've used servlets since the 0.92 spec and, while the theory is protocol independence, I've never seen anything but HTTP used with it.